# Any way to bypass the security warning when trying to run scripts off a network drive WITHOUT having admin privileges?

Tags: powershell

Is there any way to bypass the security warning when trying to run scripts off a network drive WITHOUT having admin privileges? I wrote a powershell script that needs to reside on a network drive and I cannot automatically run the script because I get this stupid error:

```
Run only scripts that you trust. While scripts from the internet can be useful, this script 
can potentially harm your
computer. If you trust this script, use the Unblock-File cmdlet to allow the script to run 
without this warning
message. Do you want to run xxx\examplefile.ps1?
[D] Do not run  [R] Run once  [S] Suspend  [?] Help (default is "D"):
```

I have no way of getting admin privileges, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Talk to your admin.  It can be set up to permit this.  There is a downside to allowing this, so your admin may say no.